# AppcompatEditText not showing cursor for android:textCursorDrawable="@null" and custom background set

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-appcompat

I am facing this issue, applied all solution , but not sure , when am i going wrong here. Please Guide me.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                            android:id="@+id/edtPassCode1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:cursorVisible="true"
                            android:focusable="true"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/bg_pass_code"
                            android:digits="0123456789"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:inputType="numberPassword"
                            android:maxLength="1"
                            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            android:paddingStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
                            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="@={viewModel.passCode1}"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/edtPassCode2"
                            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

AppcompatEditText -> background: @drawable/bg_pass_code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:left="-1dp"
        android:right="-1dp"
        android:top="-1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2px"
                android:color="#45ada8" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I have also tried to apply drawable in textCursorDrawable. but It's also not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:width="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="#000000"  />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. I have mistakenly put  `<item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>` in my `theme.xml` file of my App applied theme. I have replaced with my cursor color, & it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `android:textCursorDrawable` attribute to `@null` it is not recommanded way.

remove it and set

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                                android:id="@+id/edtPassCode1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:cursorVisible="true"
                                android:focusable="true"
                                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                                android:background="@drawable/bg_pass_code"
                                android:digits="0123456789"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                                android:inputType="numberPassword"
                                android:maxLength="1"
                                android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                                android:paddingStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
                                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:text="@={viewModel.passCode1}"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                                android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/edtPassCode2"
                                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Then create drawalble xml: `color_cursor.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <size android:width="3dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"  />
</shape>
```

You have a white color cursor on the EditText property.

Comment: Not working, And I have also tried this approach, which has been explained in question.